# Javascript, delete the last item in history (firefox addon)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, history

I have a Firefox addon that first displays a warning/info page telling the user they are being redirected (chrome://localfilter/content/wait_page.html) then redirects them to their destination.

Everything is working great.

The only thing is when/if they press the back button they see that "wait page", is there anyway to delete just that wait page from the history and leave everything else as is?
Or if that is not possible replace that wait page with another page that perhaps has just the logo (because if they read they are getting redirected and nothing happens...)

EDIT:

```
// function to see if the banned URL is on the list, then redirect
...
window.stop(); // Totally stop the page from loading.

                            window.content.location.href = "chrome://quickfilter/content/wait_page.html";



                            this.notificationBox();
                            self.timervar = setTimeout(function ()
                            {
                                self.main.redirectToAnotherUrl();
                            }, 2505);

...


redirectToAnotherUrl: function ()
            {


                window.content.location.href = self.mafiaafireFilterUrl;
                self.timervar = setTimeout(function ()
                            {
                                self.main.notificationBox();
                            }, 2005);


            }
```

Changed with replace:

```
redirectToAnotherUrl: function ()
            {


                window.content.location.replace(self.mafiaafireFilterUrl);
                self.timervar = setTimeout(function ()
                            {
                                self.main.notificationBox();
                            }, 2005);


            }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess that the best solution is not to delete the page from history but rather not add it in the first place. When you are "redirecting" to the target page you are probably using `window.location.href = ...` or something like this. Instead you should use `window.location.replace(...)` which will "replace" the current page without creating an additional history entry.

Comment: Indeed... It's a good thing that web pages aren't allowed to fiddle with the users history.

Comment: @Jan: The question is about Firefox extensions and they do have access to the browsing history. But even there, it doesn't look like selectively removing entries is possible, only methods for adding or replacing the last entry are available.

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks for replying! It's not working for me :( This is the code I am using `window.content.location.replace=//url here`

Comment: Oops, I was using it wrong, now it works... but the back button still shows the wait page :(

Comment: @Ryan: Show us some code? What exactly are you doing in your wait_page.html to "redirect" the user?

Comment: Ok, had one href and one replace... edited it to have two "replace"s and now it works, thanks guys!!